# Get request not returning expected data python

Tags: python, http, get, request

I'm trying to include a list of synonyms for words that a user inputs in my program. I want to send the word to the [Big Huge Thesaurus API](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php) which returns the data. I'm using the `requests` module to send the term but the API is only returning the HTTP response code. What I am expecting is a json object that I can extract the synonyms from. Can someone help me with this please?

```
>>import requests
>>term = 'Big'
>>Thesaurus=requests.get("http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/mykey/%s/json" % term, auth=('',''))
>>print Thesaurus

<Response [200]>
```

Comment: What type of object is Thesaurus? Have you tried doing `help(Thesaurus)` or `dir(Thesaurus)` or something similar?

Comment: @GordonBailey sr2222 answered my question below I left out a very important line in the `requesets.get` function. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to use `Thesaurus.content`, `Thesaurus.text`, or `Thesaurus.json`.  `requests.get()` returns a `requests.Response` object, and when you print that, it's just doing an implicit string cast, which for this type of object, just returns the response code formatted in the string you are seeing printed here.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot! I have 5 other requests.get() functions in my code and they're all the correct syntax and I still couldn't see my error! Thanks for pointing that out.